# Create a default value for session valid_until MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, date, default-value, session

`Server version:        5.6.22 Homebrew`

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `archived` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `valid_until` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `fk_sessions_users1_idx` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

By default, I want the valid_until column to be the current time + 1 day (or whatever). I've tried settings the 'default' to `DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 DAY)` but this failed. I also tried changing the type to `date`, `timestamp`, `time` and `year` but those give the same error:

```
ALTER TABLE `sessions` CHANGE `valid_until` `valid_until` DATETIME
 NOT NULL
 DEFAULT 'DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 DAY)'

MySQL said: Invalid default value for 'valid_until'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be
>   a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot
>   set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such
>   as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns.

The way to workaround this is to use a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_on_sessions BEFORE INSERT ON `sessions` 
FOR EACH ROW SET new.valid_until = IFNULL(new.valid_until,DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

Comment: Ah, I thought it had something to do with no calculations allowed in the default section. This verifies that, couldn't find it in the docs. Must've read over it. Thank you!